# How to keep placeholder images before running function using Array images?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

High level - I am trying to build a Slot Machine game using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. At this current step, my goal is to keep 3 blank images before the user selects the 'SPIN' button which will result in running a function that returns 3 random images from an array.

**Here is the current repo: https://github.com/feasible-creative/slotmachine**

**Here is the current repo running live: https://feasible-creative.github.io/slotmachine/**

The JavaScript snippet below works to return a random image, but my code currently has this function twice - the first instance seemingly runs automatically which makes it seem like there is a placeholder image when you first access the app (see second link above). Whereas the second instance runs as designed when the user hits spin. [Eventually all 3 images need to be randomized by the function but I think that is a later step].

```js
imgArray = ['img_1.jpg', 'img_2.jpg', 'img_3.jpg']

function getRandomImg() {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()* imgArray.length);
    selectedImg = imgArray[randomIndex]
    document.getElementById('slotResult').src = `./img/${selectedImg}`
    slotResult.className = 'casino';
}


getRandomImg();
```

To troubleshoot - I've tried removing the first instance of the above code, but that just leaves a blank space that is filled once the user hits 'SPIN'.

Comment: If you only want it to run when the user hits 'spin', don't call the function immediately after defining it  (`getRandomImg()`)

Comment: The source code of the page you linked shows that your `slotResult` image element does not have a `src` set, and so it will be blank when the page loads. So first actually sec the `src` (to whatever your placeholder image will be), and then as already mentioned, don't immediately run your spin function when the page loads.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).